# Convert JSON string to simple object with json.net

Tags: json, json.net, gson

I am using GSON on my client to stringy an object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(deviceInfo);
```

now I receive this in a header of the http request. I now need to on my server convert it back into the object.  I am not parsing it as a param so the modelbinder wont just do it for me. If there is a way to manually use to model binder. then maybe that is an option as well.

How can I do this with json.net ?

basically I want the equivalent of: `gson.fromJson(json, classOfT)`

Comment: Why can't you use Gson on Server side as well?

Comment: Cause Json.net is already installed. Why now go and install extra code? Is my Thinking

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `gson.fromJson(json, classOfT)` in json.net is

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()
```

Example:

```
public class Account
{
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
   public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
 'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
     'Admin'
   ]
 }";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```